# Kafka Client Configuration for Fixed Advertised Listener

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using Kafka-as-a-Service from a cloud provider, which requires it to be set up behind NAT gateway. The Kafka brokers can be accessed via Internet by configuring DNAT at the gateway. However, for the Kafka service used, I am not able to configure advertised listener accordingly to use the public IP, hence my clients are not able to establish connection.

Is there a way I can configure the "advertised listener" manually at the client side?

Answer (score 0):

Advertised listeners are a server-only configuration.